# Find sequence in text with at least one digit AND one letter AND some other conditions with RegEx

Tags: java, regex

I have following RegEx: `(([a-zA-Z0-9?]{4,8})(-[a-zA-Z0-9?]{4,8})+-([a-zA-Z0-9?]{4,8}))`

How can I avoid matching sequences which do not contain at least one digit AND one character (a-zA-Z)?

For example:

This text:
`Hello World 123 abc 1AB2C-D3FGH-456I7-JK8LM-NOP9Q Hello World 123 abc`
should return `1AB2C-D3FGH-456I7-JK8LM-NOP9Q`

and this:
`Hello World 123 abc 11111-1111-1111 Hello World 123 abc`

or

`Hello World 123 abc aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaa Hello World 123 abc`

should return nothing.

I develop in Java and get the group like this:

```
public List<String> getKeys() {
    keys = new ArrayList<>();
    Matcher matcher = KEY_REGEX.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        keys.add(matcher.group());
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI `[A-z]` matches more than just letters. Have a look at an [ASCII table](https://www.ascii-code.com/).

Comment: Should every part of the sequence contain a digit and a char A-Z? Or the whole sequence at least one time? Would `A1111-1111-1111` be valid? In the last case try `\b(?=[A-Z0-9-]*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z0-9-]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)+\b` https://regex101.com/r/T8Cy4C/1

Comment: The whole sequence should contain a digit and a letter at least one time. So your example would/should be valid. @Toto thank's for the hint [a-zA-Z] should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use a positive lookahead `(?=` to check for at least an occurrence of A-Z and a digit 0-9

To match the occurrences in the `-` in the lookahead to find both, you could add it to the character class.

When matching, you start matching chars A-Z0-9 and repeat a group prepending the `-` so that there are no consecutive occurrences of `-` and not at the start or at the end.

```
\b(?=[A-Z0-9-]*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z0-9-]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)+\b
```

- `\b` Word boundary
- `(?=[A-Z0-9-]*[A-Z])` Assert a char A-Z
- `(?=[A-Z0-9-]*[0-9])` Assert a digit 0-9
- `[A-Z0-9]+` Match 1+ occurrences of A-Z0-9
- `(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)+` Repeat matching 1+ occurrences of A-Z0-9 with `-` prepended
- `\b` Word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/T8Cy4C/1)

**Note** that `[A-z]` [matches more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret) than `[A-Za-z]`

---

Limiting the character class to 4-8 occurrences:

```
\b(?=[A-Z0-9-]*[A-Z])(?=[A-Z0-9-]*[0-9])[A-Z0-9]{4,8}(?:-[A-Z0-9]{4,8})+\b
```

Comment: This is working perfectly! Did not know the boundary. Just two questions: Why do I need *[A-Z] (same for the digits) in the positiv lookup and why do I need the non-capturing group?

Comment: @Chr3is In the lookahead the `[A-Z0-9-]*` is used to be able to match all the specified characters in the character class until you get to a `[A-Z]` or `[0-9]`. The `*` means 0 or more times. The non capturing group is to repeat the part as a whole `(?:-[A-Z0-9]{4,8})+`

Comment: Awesome I got it thanks :)! In my tests the RegEx works without the non capturing group too.

Comment: @Chr3is You are welcome. The grouping is used to not get matches like `A1111---1111---1111`